# input SINGULAR character to an array

Tags: arrays, c, char

i'm trying to input characters to an array

```
char ArrayChar[3]
("Enter: \n");
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
     scanf("%c", &ArrayChar[i]);
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
     printf("%c", ArrayChar[i]);
```

but i can only enter 2 characters and it can only print 2 characters. At first i thought "the size was 3, i enter 2, the last one is probably a \0". So i increase the size to 4 like this:

```
char ArrayChar[4]
("Enter: \n");
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
     scanf("%c", &ArrayChar[i]);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
     printf("%c", ArrayChar[i]);
```

but it is still stop at only 2. Now my guess is this is an "unidentified behavior" and the reason i got any result is due to a fluke? i need help please.

Comment: Assuming you are not putting spaces between the characters, a call of `getchar()` after `scanf()` should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 1 space on the `scanf` (see below `" %c"`), so that it won't read `\n` character from previous call.

```
scanf(" %c", &ArrayChar[i]);
```